# Asset allocation on Betterment.com: What's the make-up of the stock & bond portfolios?

Tags: united-states, investing, asset-allocation

Is there any Betterment user that could tell me if it's possible to have more information about how my invested money are allocated besides simple portfolio allocation between treasury bonds and stock market?

Can I know, for instance, which stocks I'm indirectly buying, in which country, in which sector, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Betterment user!

You can see the details of the Stock and Bond portfolio on Betterment's investment page:
https://www.betterment.com/about/investments/

Also, once you have an account, you can see the exact number of shares you own in your account.

Comment: Perfect link! I see that betterment invests in ETFs only. Can I opt out from any specific ETF or add others? E.G. These are random sample questions that come to my mind: I don't want to invest in the DIA. I want a higher allocation in VWO. I prefer growth ETFs to value ones. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, would I be able to do those 3 things listed above?? Thanks!